# How can I change JavaFx images sequentially rather than all at once?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm creating a program to ping many computer labs at once. On the home UI there there are images that are either red or green based on if all of the computers are pingable or not. When I call the pingAllLabs method it changes them to red or green correctly, but all at once at the end rather than as each is finished.

[This stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423109/how-to-force-java-fx-scene-refresh) is very similar but I can't/don't know how to implement it

Here is the code that does the pinging. In the Lab class it creates an arraylist of strings of the PC names that are broken.

```
@FXML
public void pingAllLabs() throws IOException{
    for (int  i = 0;i<list.listOfLabs.size();i++{
       list.listOfLabs.get(i).printBroke(fileName);
       updateImages(list.listOfLabs.get(i),i);
    }
}
```

And here is the code that actually changes the images. It retrieves the arrayList of broken pc's from the lab that is sent to it and if the list is not empty it changes the image in an arraylist of images to red or if the list is empty it changes it to green.

```
    @FXML
public void updateImages(Lab lab,int i){

    Image red = new Image("RedComp.png");
    Image green = new Image("GreenComp.png");

    ArrayList<String> list = lab.getBrokenList();

    if (!list.isEmpty()){
        images.get(i).setImage(red);
        System.out.println("Setting "+lab.getName()+" to red");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Setting to green");
        images.get(i).setImage(green);

    }

}
```

Comment: Use `Timeline`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Comment: It is still quite unclear what is going on. Am I right to say that there are multiple labs, and each lab has multiple computers, and each computer (with its pingable state) is represented by an image on the GUI? If this is so, then now the GUI updates all computers in a *single* lab all at once, or all computers in *all* labs?

Answer (score 0):

For this method here block here

```
public void pingAllLabs() throws IOException{
    for (int  i = 0;i<list.listOfLabs.size();i++{
       list.listOfLabs.get(i).printBroke(fileName);
       updateImages(list.listOfLabs.get(i),i);
    }
}
```

Make the following change

```
public void pingAllLabs() throws IOException{

    new Thread(() -> {
           for (int  i = 0;i<list.listOfLabs.size();i++) {
           list.listOfLabs.get(i).printBroke(fileName);
           updateImages(list.listOfLabs.get(i),i);
           }
       }).start();

    }
}
```

And change this block

```
 if (!list.isEmpty()){
        images.get(i).setImage(red);
        System.out.println("Setting "+lab.getName()+" to red");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Setting to green");
        images.get(i).setImage(green);

    }
```

make the following change

```
 if (!list.isEmpty()){
        Platform.runLater( () -> images.get(i).setImage(red))
        System.out.println("Setting "+lab.getName()+" to red");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Setting to green");
         Platform.runLater( () -> images.get(i).setImage(green))

    }
```

So now you wont block the UI thread and also allow the updates to be done asynchronously.

**Insights**

The problem is akin to the question you linked, you are running the for loop on the JavaFx Application thread, which causes the model changes not to be rendered immediately but only after you return from `pingAllLab()` which returns only after `updateImages()` returns which contains the loop. The above code runs the image adding logic on a different thread and then posts the updates to the UI event queue using `Platform.runLater()`.

Hence, whenever you write code that affects the UI in some way, use `Platform.runLater()`